# Kartik-v select not populating data in the form

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I need help on the select widget for kartik as used in yii2 advanced template. 
Data is being fetched correctly and i can print it using the print_r function.

```html
<?php
        $facultiesData = Faculties::find()
                        ->select(['faculty_id','faculty_name'])
                        ->asArray()
                        ->all();
        $facultiesData = ArrayHelper::map( $facultiesData, 'faculty_id','faculty_name' );

        print_r($facultiesData); //print values on screen

     ?>
```

the problem is,this data is not being populated in the form field with kartik select widget

```html
<?=  $form->field($model, 'faculty_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => $facultiesData,
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'choose property ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
     ]); 
  ?>
```

this is what is showing
[image]

Thanks in advance. I will appreciate any lead or help

Comment: is not clear where you have the first part of code  .. in view  ?? .. in controlleer?   .. update you question and add the controller/action and the view code please ?

Comment: Try removing `->asArray()` from your query

Comment: @gmc I tried removing ->asArray() but doesnt work either

Comment: Any error in the js console?

Comment: @scaisEdge the code is in view. Here's the URL http://localhost/moamis/frontend/web/index.php?r=student-reg-details/create

Comment: @samuelkungu    ... how do you think is possible acces to localhost ... loacalhost  ..mean "on your pc"

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. In the code

```
<?php
    $facultiesData = Faculties::find()
                    ->select(['faculty_id','faculty_name'])
                    ->asArray()
                    ->all();
    $facultiesData = ArrayHelper::map( $facultiesData, 'faculty_id','faculty_name' );

    print_r($facultiesData); //print values on screen

 ?>
```

I removed "->select()->asArray() to remain with find()->all() "

The function asArray() returns values as [34=>"any"] but the widget requires data as 34=>"any" as for my understaing.